# How to integrate/install Beeline UI Editor for opensource apache-haoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, beeline

Can we configure Beeline UI for open source hadoop version ?
If so how to do it ? Any url/document Please?

I am new to Bigdata.
It is decided to use as HIVE as staging area in my project.
My company as of now using open-source apache-spark i.e. spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7.

Data fed from oracle to --> Parquet then Spark processes data...
Going forward they want to use HIVE as staging area to process data.

For that team need an Editor for HIVE.

On the net i found Beeline can be used for it.

But 
Can we configure Beeline UI for open source hadoop version ?
If so how to do it ? 
Any url/document Please?

Which version i need to use ?

Answer (score 1):

Beeline isn't a UI, it's a shell similar to hive shell.  It is part of Hive so you shouldn't have to do anything special as it's versioned with Hive.

If you want a GUI, you should look at Hue.

#### References

- [Hive beeline code](https://github.com/apache/hive/tree/master/beeline)
- [Migrating from Hive CLI to Beeline](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/02/migrating-from-hive-cli-to-beeline-a-primer/)
- [Hue](http://gethue.com/)

Comment: thank you, Does the Hue works with apache hadoop i.e. open source ? if so how to integrate/configure it ?

Comment: @tk21, Hue is of Cloudera ? does it work with apache hadoop i.e. open source?

Comment: Hue supports most vendors of Hadoop including Cloudera, Hortonworks and MapR.  Look at http://gethue.com/how-to-configure-hue-in-your-hadoop-cluster/.

Comment: thank you but i am not using any Vendor hadoop , i am using apache opensource hadoop , does this support it ?

Comment: It does but it's easier to configure if you're using a vendor-supported distribution.